# Secondary backup server

Tags: linux, failover, centos6

I've been given a task to implement a backup solution in the event of our website goes down. It is a dedicated server running centos 6.

From what i've experience on our server, our server may go down because of PHP application crash or hardware failure.

I have couple of questions:

1. In the first case, is it possible to get the server restart the PHP automatically, how can I do that? Because in my mind, if it is only the application that goes down, probably I can still make use of the server itself.
2. In the second case, can I redirect a request to a secondary server? How can I do that? What do I need other than another server?

For now it is gonna be a simple server which shows the user a static landing page so later the system notify us via email that the primary server went down so that we can restart the server manually.

Is it possible to setup just a vps or even a shared server for the secondary server ? As I think there is only gonna be a static page.

Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to switch to another handler such as fastcgi the performance will be great than before

2- what about some soulution such as failover or high availability cluster it's really amazing

Regards

Comment: 1 - I need something that can automatically monitor the PHP application. Can fastcgi do it? 2 - Yeahh, I think something such as failover, but I have no idea how to do it, can you give me a link on how to do it?